# Optimize/rewrite LINQ query with GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a count of unique Foos and Bars grouped by Name, on the following data set.

```
Id  |   IsActive    |   Name    |   Foo     |   Bar
1   |       1       |   A       |   11      |   null
2   |       1       |   A       |   11      |   null
3   |       1       |   A       |   null    |   123
4   |       1       |   B       |   null    |   321
```

I expect the result on the above data to be:

```
Expected:
A = 2;
B = 1;
```

I tried to group by Name,Foo,Bar and then group by Name again with a count to get the "row" count. But that didn't give me the correct result. (or the ToDictionary threw a duplicate key, I played around with this a lot so can't quite remember)

```
db.MyEntity
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Foo, x.Bar })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.Name, Count = x.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count);
```

So I came up with this LINQ query. But it's rather slow.

```
db.MyEntity
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
        x =>
            x.Where(y => y.Foo != null).Select(y => y.Foo).Distinct().Count() +
            x.Where(y => y.Bar != null).Select(y => y.Bar).Distinct().Count());
```

How can I optimize it?

Here's the entity for refernece

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Foo { get; set; }
    public int? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

### Edit

I also tried this query

```
db.MyEntity
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Foo, x.Bar })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Name)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

But that threw a timeout exception :(

Comment: Why does it need optimising?

Comment: I dont think it can be optimized. You use minimal set of operations to get desired result.

Comment: "I tried to group by Name,Foo,Bar and then group by Name again with a count to get the "row" count. " Seems like that should have worked - can you [post that query?

Comment: @DStanley I added the double groupby query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query is extremely inefficient because you're doing much of the work (everything involved in building the dictionary) on the client side, without being able to use the database to do your projections.  This is a problem both because the database (especially if these values are indexed) can do this work faster than the client, and also because doing the projections on the database involves much less data being sent over the network.

So simply do your projections *before* you group the data.

```
var activeItems = db.MyEntity.Where(x => x.IsActive);

var query = activeItems.Select(x => new { Name, Value = x.Foo}).Distinct()
    .Concat(activeItems.Select(x => new { Name, Value = x.Bar}).Distinct())        
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Name)
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = Group.Count()})
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Count);
```

Comment: Ok, this is also inefficient, you are selecting all rows from db. Selects are with unions etc.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri What makes you think it's going to select all rows from the database?  All it's actually pulling are the names and the counts of the items in the group.

Comment: @usr Edited to also project out the count first.

Comment: this is what database should return in order the query to be efficient `1 A 3
1 B 1`. Your query returns `C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1 A 1 1 A 11
1 A 1 1 A 123
1 B 1 1 B 123`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I fail to see how the query ended up pulling back tons of data that doesn't even exist in the database.  Sounds like you've got something weird going on there.  But yes, it was doing *almost* all of the work in the DB but not the very last step.  I edited it to also do the final projection in the DB several minutes before your last comment, so even that no longer applies.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, now it is grouping at database level and returns only 2 rows :)

Answer (score 1):

Your aim is to produce the following query:

```
select Name, count(distinct Foo) + count(distinct Bar)
from myEntity
where IsActive = 1
group by Name
```

This is the minimal query to get what you want.
But LINQ seems to overcomplicate everything as much as possible :)

Your aim is to do as much at database level as possible. Now your query is translated to:

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project2].[id] AS [id], 
    [Project2].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
    [Project2].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
    [Project2].[Foo] AS [Foo], 
    [Project2].[Bar] AS [Bar]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Distinct1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Extent2].[id] AS [id], 
        [Extent2].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
        [Extent2].[Foo] AS [Foo], 
        [Extent2].[Bar] AS [Bar], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
            FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[IsActive] = 1 ) AS [Distinct1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[IsActive] = 1) AND ([Distinct1].[Name] = [Extent2].[Name])
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[Name] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
```

It selects everything from database and performs grouping at application layer, that is inefficient.

The query of @Servy:

```
var activeItems = db.MyEntity.Where(x => x.IsActive);

var query = activeItems.Select(x => new { Name, Value = x.Foo}).Distinct()
.Concat(activeItems.Select(x => new { Name, Value = x.Bar}).Distinct())        
.Where(x => x != null)
.GroupBy(pair => pair.Name)
.Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = Group.Count()})
.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Count);
```

is translated to:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C2], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[Name] AS [K1], 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [Distinct1].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent1].[Foo] AS [Foo]
            FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[IsActive] = 1) AND ([Extent1].[Foo] IS NOT NULL)
        )  AS [Distinct1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        [Distinct2].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent2].[Bar] AS [Bar]
            FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[IsActive] = 1) AND ([Extent2].[Bar] IS NOT NULL)
        )  AS [Distinct2]) AS [UnionAll1]
    GROUP BY [UnionAll1].[Name]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

It is much better.

I have tried the following:

```
var activeItems = (from o in db.SomeTables
                   where o.IsActive
                   group o by o.Name into gr
                   select new { gr.Key, cc = gr.Select(c => c.Foo).Distinct().Count(c => c != null) + 
                                             gr.Select(c => c.Bar).Distinct().Count(c => c != null) }).ToDictionary(c => c.Key);
```

This is translated to:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Project5].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project5].[C1] + [Project5].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project3].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent3].[Bar] AS [Bar]
            FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ([Extent3].[IsActive] = 1) AND ([Project3].[Name] = [Extent3].[Name]) AND ([Extent3].[Bar] IS NOT NULL)
        )  AS [Distinct3]) AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Distinct1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                [Extent2].[Foo] AS [Foo]
                FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Extent2].[IsActive] = 1) AND ([Distinct1].[Name] = [Extent2].[Name]) AND ([Extent2].[Foo] IS NOT NULL)
            )  AS [Distinct2]) AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
            FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[IsActive] = 1
        )  AS [Distinct1]
    )  AS [Project3]
)  AS [Project5]
```

Much the same but without unions as in second version.

Conclusion:

**I would create a view and import it in model if table is quite large and performance is crucial. Otherwise stick on 3rd version or 2rd version of @Servy. Performance should be tested of course.**

Comment: This is an exactly equivalent query.  `Where` followed by a `Count` is the exact same thing as a `Count` accepting a predicate.

Comment: @Servy, may be, I can not check at the moment what statement is generated by linq.

Comment: Why would it be any different?  They're conceptually identical operations.  How do you *expect* them to differ?

Comment: You are counting duplicate items multiple times.

Comment: @Servy, thx, corrected. Still returning only 2 rows of course.

Comment: But when it's two rows *containing the wrong result* that's a pretty major problem.

Comment: @Servy, I have corrected my select to pick distinct counts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just modify your initial query slightly to get what you want:

```
db.MyEntity
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Foo, x.Bar })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Name)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

When you add `Count()` to the second grouping you are counting the duplicate values for the three-part key.  You only want to count the distinct values for each three-part key, so you count *after* grouping by `Name`.

Comment: I also realized that as I was editing the post :). However I'm getting a timeout when I run it. I'll have to look into why that is :/

Answer (score -2):

Only advice about question can be not use DISTINCT for better performance.Use grouping.

Please look to this [link](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/546/using-grouping-instead-of-distinct-in-entity-framework-to-optimize-performance)

Comment: That's saying that you shouldn't be using `Distinct` **with a custom equality comparer**, because of course, SQL won't know what to do with such a comparer, so your only option is to pull all of the data into memory at that point.  When you don't have a custom equality comparer there's no problem at all with using `Distinct`.